# Entity Framework (EF) Model First Approach + Ms Unity dependency injection container

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unity-container

thanks in advance for your support. I would like to receive guidance in order to implement Ms Unity dependency injection container with EF Model First approach by using edmx files in an asp.net MVC project.

At this moment I found many projects using EF Code First + unity but I was not able to find a project implementing data model edmx files with Unity DI.
brgds!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The decision to use Model First development shouldn't affect how you would use Dependency Injection, whether with Unity or any other container.  The objects generated from the edmx file aren't ones that you would be injecting.  You will still need to code your own abstractions - things like IRepository or IUnitOfWork - and those would be dependencies that you inject.

See, for example, [this similar question and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8448791/entity-framework-4-db-first-dependency-injection).

Comment: thank you @qes , I read that post previously to post this one. I found very interesting the article http://huyrua.wordpress.com/2010/07/13/entity-framework-4-poco-repository-and-specification-pattern/ . probably I have to expand further my question, things like: which area of unity implementation I have to define/edit in order to map to edmx or file (in case of code-first).. any open source project using edmx files with Unity to take for inspiration.. etc. thank you for your reply..